# Is there a way to "hack" the power options in Windows 10, e.g. change from to 100% instead of 60?

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, power-management, lenovo-laptop

In [this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-10/Power-Manager-for-Windows-10/m-p/2129075#M794) link is said

> There is nothing that a user needs to do manually, to maximize battery health on these batteries. For this reason, we don't provide any utility to manually manage battery charge thresholds on Windows 10.

95% of the time my laptop is plugged into the charger, so Windows considers that it's healthier for the battery to not charge fully which is logical. But let's say I have to go somewhere for a day or so and I need it fully charged. Basically, I need to change it manually.

So, does anyone know how to "hack" that?

Lenovo G510

Comment: As stated in your link it is in the battery firmware not windows that controls this, and only Lenovo could write software to change this.

Comment: Please post the exact model of Lenovo you have.

Comment: Could you try this [registry hack](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1/Changing-Charge-Threshold-on-ThinkPads-under-Windows-8-without/m-p/2121077#M7877) also under Windows 10? I've seen a claim it was also working under Windows 10 (if I understood correctly).

Answer (score 0):

1. get the latest power manager from Lenovo website
2. run the downloaded file, it will fail saying " ... doesn't work on this version of Windows ..." or similar
3. go to C:\DRIVERS\VISTA\PWRMGRV and change setup.exe compatibility mode to windows 7
4. go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx#adkwin10 and download "Windows ADK for Windows 10, Version 1511"
5. run it and you only need to install "compatibility administrator"
6. run "compatibility administrator", on the left, under System Database->Applications, click "Lenovo Power Manager"
7. on the right, right mouse click setup.exe and select "disable entry"
8. now you are on the way installing and using power manager
   good luck!

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/lenovo-power-manager-does-not-work-with-windows-10/dbeac5b7-f422-46cd-a0dd-e716d34b3f3b?auth=1)